# Rails .exists? not comparing unicode characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicode, encoding

I have a simple blog-like application where a post can belong to a category. The thing is, my application is in French and one of the categories is "l'épidémie de COVID-19". When I check if the category already exists, it always returns false:

```
if Category.exists?(title: title)

# -> Always false when the title is 'l'épidémie de COVID-19', even though it does already exist
```

The code works fine if I use titles like "Covid-19" or "Environnement", but not when I have 'special' characters like é, è, etc.

Is there a way to solve this? Thank you

Edit:
Databse: sqlite3

Column type: t.string "category"

Generated SQL:

```
SELECT 1 AS one FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."category" = ? LIMIT ?  [["category", "l'épidémie de COVID-19"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

Comment: What db are you using and what is title column type? And also - could you add to the question the sql that Rails generated?

Comment: @JoelBlum Alright, I edited the question and added the information

Comment: Are you actually going to use SQLite in production? If not I would switch now instead of wasting the time on getting it to work on SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `encoding: utf8` in your `config/database.yml` and

`config.encoding = "utf-8"` in `config/application.rb`